# How to check the masking of the password field for an android (native) app using Experitest? -

Tags: c#, android, automated-tests, experitest

I am in the process of writing the automated test for the android app using  Experitest (http://experitest.com/) .The test requires to check the masking of the password field but I am struggling to achieve it as experitest is not returning the field type.

Is it possible to check the masking of a field for android apps? The underlying automation code is written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check masking of password then please check password property which is set to true/false. if it's true then the password displays with the * sign.

[image]